# How do I find the sum of first N numbers common to 2 APs?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, arithmetic, computational-mathematics

Here is the question -

> Certain numbers appear in both arithmetic progressions 17, 21, 25, ...
>   and 16, 21, 26, ... . Find the sum of first 100 numbers appearing in
>   both progressions.

The solution given is -

> (1) Denoting the *n*th and *m*th terms of the 2 progressions by T*n*
>   and T*m*', we have
>
> (2) T*n* = 17 + (*n* - 1) . 4 = 4n + 13 and
>
> (3) T*m*' = 16 + (*m* - 1) . 5 = 5m + 11
>
> (4) For common terms, we must have
>
> (5) T*n* = T*m*' => 4n + 13 = 5m + 11 => 5m = 2 . (2n + 1)
>
> (6) This shows that 2n + 1 = 5k, k = 1, 3, 5, ...
>
> (7) Hence, the common terms are given by -
>
> (8) T(2k)' = 5 . 2k + 11 = 10k + 11, k = 1, 3, 5, ...
>
> (9) Hence, sum of first 100 common terms = 21 + 41 + 61 + ... =
>   (100/2)(2x21+(100-1).20) = 101100

I can understand clearly till line (5) in the solution, but after that, whatever is done confuses me. Could anyone explain how to go about such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sequence has the form $13+4 m$, while the second has the form $11+5 n$.  These are equal when $5 n-4 m = 2$, or, for any nonnegative integer $k$, $m=2+5 k$ and $n=2+4 k$ for members of both sequences.  Thus, the form of the sequence is $a_k = 11+5 (2+4 k) = 21+20 k$.  The sum of the first 100 of these terms is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{99} (21+20 k) = 100 \cdot 21 + \frac12 (20) (100)(99) = 101100$$

**ADDENDUM**

Looks like you were confused about how to express the common term $a_k$.  Here, I just made a table of ordered pairs $(m,n)$ that satisfied $5 n-4 m=2$, which isn't hard.  Once you see the pattern, the above expressions jump out.

Comment: How did you get m=2+5k and n=2+4k for members of both sequences?

Comment: @user3164272: see the Addendum.  I just made a table of ordered pairs that satisfied $5 n - 4 m = 2$, and then numbered each such ordered pair.

Comment: Okay, thank you. That helped.

Comment: @RonGordon , where did you put a table of ordered pairs?